# Separate Appstore territory

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have an iOS app on the Swedish Appstore and I'm now looking to launch the app in the US. I understand that I will have to use localizedstring to support both Swedish and English in the app.

My problem is that I want to show a different "feed" in the app in the US that can't only be based on the language setting on the users phone. Is there any way to detect what Appstore territory the app has been downloaded from?

Comment: You can know the location from the device, and if the user in US location then do your extra stuff in your App. For example suppose you want to show some extra button for US users, then you can manage the button to show based on the user's device location. Hope it make sense.

Comment: I don't want to force the user to share his location. I'm guessing I have to use Locale.current.regionCode or Locale.current.identifier? Thanks!

Comment: Found it, think i will go for regionCode: [https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-detect-which-country-a-user-is-in](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-detect-which-country-a-user-is-in)